default datetime value at django form
i'm trying to use a default value
class MSeguimientoEtnicoForm(forms.ModelForm):
... 
fecha_reporte = forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Establece la fecha y hora actuales como valor inicial para fecha_reporte
        self.fields['fecha_reporte'].initial = timezone.now()

template:
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fechaReporte">Fecha Reporte: </label>
        <input class="form-control" id="fechaReporte" type="datetime-local" name="fecha_reporte" required>
    </div>
                            
</div>

but doesn't take the timezone.now() value at the view template
view and default value don't working
i was searching for aroud but i didn't found nothing

Perhaps you could try to use datetime.now() instead of timezone.now()?
So, in your forms.py file, do:
from datetime import datetime

...
self.fields['fecha_reporte'].initial = datetime.now()

Hope this helps.
